# Trying to create a custom validator for date in excel

Tags: excel, validation

As I want to create vailidator for a specific date format could be enter. I want date should be entered in text format as latter I will upload this sheet in my .net project to a Data Table. I am not using date format because of past conversion issues in date format.

I came up with a formula that return true or false for enter text(dd/MM/yyyy).

```
=AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))<30,(VALUE(MID(A1,4,2))<13),LEN(A1)<12,((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))=2)))
```

The problem I am facing right now is that, it works for some input and does not for certain input:

[image]

sheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoQmOkpNF33ShqsCwzrQthEMHSV97Q

Comment: My mistake, thanks for edit @uderscore_d

Comment: What is the format of cells in column A? Why isn't `12/11/2014` a date? (Or should it be `TRUE`, your formula just isn't working?

Comment: It's simple text,that's why I am using "value" to compare with integer when required. Why it's calculating Len =5 , didn't get that.

Comment: Sorry everyone, @BruceWayne was right that particular cell was automatically getting convert into date, that's why all values are coming wrong. I just found it when I open that excel on my phone. By way the thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: @BruceWayne now I have change the format cell to text, in output section it is coming true, but when I try to implement the same formula in  validation.It fails there, even giving the same input. Any suggestions.

Comment: Hey @BruceWayne, I have find the problem. As I was working in kingsoft when I was putting "=" before formula it was saying wrong formula in validation formula box. So I was not putting that = . Latter I found It was compulsory. Now I am trying to put that formula for all cells in as for A2 cell formula is work on A2. For A3 cell formula should work on A3. Any quick hint you can give.